# Controlling multiple Chromecast Receivers from one Sender?

Tags: google-cast

Is it possible to write a Chrome extension (or Android app) that creates multiple Senders, each connecting to a different Receiver?

In other words, I need to build an interface from which an operator can control the streams on multiple different Chromecasts in the vicinity - each will be playing a different video stream.

I understand from other posts that the chrome.cast API does not allow for this - that the Chrome extension may acts as a single Sender only? This restriction seems arbitrary - I read somewhere that someone was able to control two devices by running two different versions of Chrome, so if this restriction exists in the Chrome API, it's not due to any limitation of the underlying protocol, correct? (what then, politics?)

Is there a lower-level API (perhaps on Android?) that would permit you to create multiple Senders and connect them to different Receivers?

I've seen some apps (such as Videostream) which appear to continue to run on the Receiver after you've closed the Sender. Might it be possible to, for example, launch a Receiver app on multiple devices, one at a time, have them identify themselves and connect to a local webserver, e.g. via WebSockets, and then have my webserver send messages to those Receiver apps to ask them to change videostreams?

As a last resort, is there an open specification of the underlying protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to stop you from writing a sender app that connects to a chromecast, launches an app and then disconnects from that device while letting the chromecast continue running the app; you would need to make sure that you do not stop the receiver when it detects that there are no connected devices. Then, on the sender side, you can repeat the same process but this time connect to a second device and so on. The important thing to keep in mind is that your sender device cannot hold multiple concurrent connections to multiple devices (MediaRouter is a global instance); this means you cannot receive messages (status updates, etc) from different Cast devices except the one you are directly connected to at that time. Also, there is nothing to stop a different user to connect to one of these devices and launch a different app.

To answer your other question, the underlying protocol is not open.

Comment: For another user to "hijack" my Receivers, he would have to be logged onto my local wi-fi network though, right?

Comment: Yes, unless you have enabled guest mode in which case they can be "close" to your device to be able to cast to it.