# What protocol to use when sending video to multiple devices simultaneously

Tags: streaming, chromecast, rtp, dlna

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but I have a question..
I am working on a students project where we want to stream a video from one server to multiple devices. But the video should only play on one display at a time. The other displays should be black. But if you switch to another display, the video should continue seamlessly. (Please ask if you need clarification)

The video outputs can be plain displays or with additional servers so a wide range of protocols can be implemented. Wifi connection is possible. Web solutions for running the video in a browser is also possible.

I thought of a lot of alternatives like DLNA, RTP or Chromecast. But I don't know where to start and which is the right solution. It is important that the video that is streamed from the server can be continued on any display seamlessly.

If would mean much to me if you'd give me a hint.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible. A sender cannot hold multiple concurrent connections to multiple devices as stated in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33726391/5995040). Also since `MediaRouter` is a global instance you cannot receive messages (status updates, etc) from different Cast devices except the one you are directly connected to at that time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. If one sender can hold only one connection to one receiver, what about creating multiple senders? For example, I could run multiple docker containers on the server. A fourth docker container would manage the three container which would handle the streams to the chromecasts?